# What kind of LDA performs 'fitcdiscr' function?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, lda, linear-discriminant

I know that the new [`fitcdiscr` MATLAB® function](https://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcdiscr.html) can perform several discriminant analysis, such as LDA or QDA. However, the mentions about 'regularization' and 'bayesian' inside the MATLAB® help confuse me.

What kind of discriminant analysis is performed if `fitcdiscr` uses the default parameters? Do it use Bayesian Linear Discriminant Analysis (BLDA), Fisher's LDA (FLDA), or some kind of Regularized LDA (rLDA)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What kind of discriminant analysis is performed if fitcdiscr uses the default parameters?

According to [Matlab's documentation](https://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcdiscr.html), it seems they are using "Regularized linear discriminant analysis" as default **'DiscrimType'**.

Take a look to the image below:

[fitcdiscr default discriminant type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3gkY.png)